# Parse old schema.org with schemaorg-java

Tags: java, schema.org

I have some problem reading the "documentation" of [schemaorg-java](https://github.com/google/schemaorg-java) from google. What I'm trying to understand is how to deserialize "wrong" type of schema.org jsonld files.

I've found a site that use mainEntityOfPage in the wrong way by setting it to "true" instead of following schema.org's structure. I thought it's an old version of it, but I haven't found any versioning or citation about mainEnitityOfPage being boolean.

So my question: Is there a way to either deserialize the whole schema and skip the wrong properties or maybe a way to use this old format?

snippet:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Recipe",
  "mainEntityOfPage": true, [...]
```

Comment: Side note: In Schema.org these kind of values are not considered to be "wrong". Schema.org only defines "expected" values, but authors are free *not* to follow this advice.

Comment: @unor I think we can safely consider the project dead. I can't find people using it, I don't see any kind of documentation and I really doubt they want me to correct the whole json ld before parsing. Pity that there are only two libraries for jsonld.